# Merging two atributes columns in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, merge, table

I have a shapefile that is a result of a merge between a land use chart (with two gaps) and two files to fill the gaps, but the atributes in the Land Use Chart are designated by "LEG" and in the Gap Charts are designated by "COS".
In the merged chart, I got two columns that I would like to merge.
They are both listed as "Text".
I already tried the Field Calculator but the SQL code was invalid.
Could anyone help me?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you edit your question and insert a screen capture showing the field calculator sql statement you are using plus the geoprocessing result error message?

Answer (score 2):

In field calculator, if you are merging two text fields, put single or double quotes around each field name. Also, make sure to see the combined length of these two fields do not exceed the length of the column you are calculating on.

Answer (score 1):

The first Feature Class you add to the tool defines the output scheme, which is entirely editable. In the Field Map dialog of Merge, you can right-click a field to add input fields or remove fields; under properties, you can change field types, field widths. You can Delete fields for the output. With the plus button, you can add a new field.